# On Ubuntu Desktop ssh does not read first line of authorized_keys

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, hyper-v, ubuntu-22.04

Seems nobody has run into this based on my searches so posting this here. Installed Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 on Hyper-V behind NAT on Windows 11 Pro. Desktop version has no ssh preinstalled, so installed it via apt later and then when I copied the my SSH public key to the VM and tried to ssh to it, the key didn't work and ssh kept asking me for password.

All my permissions are correct and public key is copied correctly to the right location.

To get this to work I had to make an empty first line on the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and then everything worked fine. Whatever public key I put to the first line, it seems that is not read. I checked and there are no strange characters there. SSH server just ignores whatever is on the first line. I never saw this before, and I've done this thousands of times on many different distros. Default sshd settings have not been changed. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Debug logs below:

```
#when key is on first line
Jan  1 21:05:37 megak-dev-vm sshd[3949]: debug1: userauth_pubkey: publickey test pkalg ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 pkblob ECDSA SHA256:vXBAZU+zrZKurGyRQnQZ8DPCnw4dwgZ63oO6VBsw8Oc [preauth]
Jan  1 21:05:37 megak-dev-vm sshd[3949]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
Jan  1 21:05:37 megak-dev-vm sshd[3949]: debug1: trying public key file /home/megak/.ssh/authorized_keys
Jan  1 21:05:37 megak-dev-vm sshd[3949]: debug1: fd 5 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Jan  1 21:05:37 megak-dev-vm sshd[3949]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Jan  1 21:05:37 megak-dev-vm sshd[3949]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
Jan  1 21:05:37 megak-dev-vm sshd[3949]: debug1: trying public key file /home/megak/.ssh/authorized_keys2
Jan  1 21:05:37 megak-dev-vm sshd[3949]: debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/megak/.ssh/authorized_keys2': No such file or directory
Jan  1 21:05:37 megak-dev-vm sshd[3949]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Jan  1 21:05:37 megak-dev-vm sshd[3949]: Failed publickey for megak from 192.168.42.1 port 57170 ssh2: ECDSA SHA256:vXBAZU+zrZKurGyRQnQZ8DPCnw4dwgZ63oO6VBsw8Oc


#when key is on second line
Jan  1 21:15:16 megak-dev-vm sshd[4011]: debug1: userauth_pubkey: publickey test pkalg ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 pkblob ECDSA SHA256:vXBAZU+zrZKurGyRQnQZ8DPCnw4dwgZ63oO6VBsw8Oc [preauth]
Jan  1 21:15:16 megak-dev-vm sshd[4011]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
Jan  1 21:15:16 megak-dev-vm sshd[4011]: debug1: trying public key file /home/megak/.ssh/authorized_keys
Jan  1 21:15:16 megak-dev-vm sshd[4011]: debug1: fd 5 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Jan  1 21:15:16 megak-dev-vm sshd[4011]: debug1: /home/megak/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: matching key found: ECDSA SHA256:vXBAZU+zrZKurGyRQnQZ8DPCnw4dwgZ63oO6VBsw8Oc
Jan  1 21:15:16 megak-dev-vm sshd[4011]: debug1: /home/megak/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
Jan  1 21:15:16 megak-dev-vm sshd[4011]: Accepted key ECDSA SHA256:vXBAZU+zrZKurGyRQnQZ8DPCnw4dwgZ63oO6VBsw8Oc found at /home/megak/.ssh/authorized_keys:2
Jan  1 21:15:16 megak-dev-vm sshd[4011]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Jan  1 21:15:16 megak-dev-vm sshd[4011]: Postponed publickey for megak from 192.168.42.1 port 57586 ssh2 [preauth]
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `ssh-copy-id username@server` to generate `authorized_keys` file ? - Instead of doing this manually.

Comment: How did you check the file's contents for "strange characters"?

Comment: @u1686_grawity by viewing the file with "vim -b" and using `:set list`

Comment: @hidigoudi no, windows ssh does not support this. I did try with `type ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub | ssh megak@192.168.42.42 'cat > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'` which is the "old school method" when copy id is not available.

Comment: By doing the same process to create the `authorized_keys` file, do you have the same behavior with another `OpenSSH` version / another Linux system ?

Comment: I think I have found your issue, I'm able to reproduce it in my environment. I will write an answer if my theory is correct. - I think that it is an **file encoding** issue. Windows by default encodes files in `UTF16` which is detected in Linux as `application/octet-stream; charset=binary` if you run this command : `file -bi ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` - This file encoding **does not work** with authorized_keys file, and the SSH daemon refuses to authenticate you with your key. When you modify the file, I guess in Linux directly, the encoding format change to `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`.

Comment: On my side, I don't see any other explanation of this behavior (except a bug on your SSH version).

Comment: @hidigoudi well, this is a good theory, however if this were the case, it would have worked if I placed the authorized key on the first line of the file after editing this in linux via `vim`, which it did not (and still doesn't). In fact if I create the file in linux and just copy paste the whole public key into vim via terminal, the same effect happens. So I am pretty sure this is on the guest OS side. I should note that this is first time I am doing something like this on Ubuntu Desktop and not Server variant. If that makes any difference...

Comment: Ok thank you for update. Really weird bug ! Indeed, it looks like an issue with `Ubuntu Desktop OS`. I never saw this behavior before. - How did you create the file in Ubuntu ? - What is the file encoding of the file once edited with `vim` ? - On my side, I edited the file with `nano`, it's maybe a different behavior with it. - Do you have the same behavior with another OS ?

Comment: File encoding is utf8 and no, this does not happen on any other OS. More than that, it does not happen on non-vm Ubuntu Desktop either. I think that since this is so hard to reproduce, we can leave it as is for now, and if someone has the same problem, they can at least find the workaround in my question